# Function to stop all audio from HTML using a MAP with area ID

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a simple HTML with a Image MAP which points to 21 areas, everyone of them references to a JS function that plays the audio referred in the code as you can see:

```js
function playSound(soundfile) {
    var audio = new Audio(soundfile);
    audio.play();
}

function StopAllAudio() {
var audio = document.getElementByTagName("area");
  for(var audioS : AudioSource in allAudioSources) {
   audioS.Stop();
  }
 }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css">
      <title>Mapa de Sons de l'Escola</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p><strong>MAPA DE SONS DE L'ESCOLA</strong></p>
      <p>
         <img src="BP_mapa.jpg" alt="mapasons" width="1200" height="1034" usemap="#Map" border="0" onclick="myFunction()" />
         <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="poly" coords="571,194,612,176,623,198,580,218" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/1.mp3');" alt="1"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="1007,162,1043,227" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/2.mp3');" alt="2" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="1047,162,1083,227" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/3.mp3');" alt="3"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="1088,162,1123,227" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/4.mp3');" alt="4" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="604,276,35" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/5.mp3');" alt="5" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="850,295,57" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/6.mp3');" alt="6" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="608,382,38" alt="7" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/7.mp3');"/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="844,376,854,376,853,373,867,373,867,376,877,376,877,399,868,408,854,409,844,400,844,376" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/8.mp3');" alt="8"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="618,452,679,545" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/9.mp3');" alt="9"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="802,435,925,488" alt="10" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/10.mp3');" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="945,460,1052,504" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/11.mp3');" alt="11"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="799,508,1052,548" alt="12" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/12.mp3');" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="586,572,35" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/13.mp3');" alt="13" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="399,609,464,753" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/14.mp3');" alt="14"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="300,792,345,820" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/15.mp3');" alt="15"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="347,792,392,820" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/16.mp3');" alt="16"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="393,792,440,820" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/17.mp3');" alt="17"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="127,813,185,866" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/18.mp3');" alt="18"/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="208,819,250,820,250,851,458,851,454,859,459,859,446,888,440,888,436,897,439,898,250,896,250,874,207,874,208,819" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/19.mp3');" alt="19"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="127,869,185,922" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/20.mp3');" alt="20"/>
            <area shape="poly" coords="252,980,399,980,420,936,252,935" href="JavaScript: playSound('sounds/21.mp3');" alt="21" />
         </map>
      </p>
      <button id="botoParar" onclick="StopAllAudio()">Para Audios</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Moreover, I have a function in JS which has to STOP all audio when button is pressed "StopAllAudio()" which is not working, cause when I press any other audio it keeps running on the background with the new audio.

Is there any function which can stop all other audios when the next one is pressed or any function to stop all audio manually and then you can play another sound?

Many thanks.

Best regards,

Mario.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. What is the reason for the `xmlHttp.ResponseText`? It doesn't look like you're doing an ajax call, and at the moment the function will fail because `xmlHttp` is undefined.

Comment: Hi Enzo, thanks for the quick response. The xmlHttp.ResponseText is because I was trying some alternatives, I'm not able to stop the audio from the document.

First of all, I had another function:

function StopAllAudio() {
  for(var audioS : AudioSource in allAudioSources) {
   audioS.Stop();
  }
 }

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is because function "playSound" just create new instance of Audio object and start play. Newly created object is not stored inside area

```
<area shape="poly" coords="571,194,612,176,623,198,580,218" href="JavaScript: playAreaSound('1');" alt="1">
<audio
  src="sounds/1.mp3">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
</area>
```

```
playAreaSound(areaId) {
   const audio = document.getElementBy...;//Anything you want using passed areaId
   audio.play();
}
```

and StopAllAudio should work then.